# $E\backslash C$ is relatively open in $E$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

If $E \subset  \mathbb R^n$ and $C \subset E$ is relatively closed in $E$, then $E\backslash C$ is relatively open in $E$.

Comment: I am guessing your ambient space should be $\mathbb R^n$, right ?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly fine. I would add your proof as an answer and accept it. (N.B. next time add some context such as the ambient space and topology. Be as self-contained as possible.)

Comment: @A.P., I decided to follow your suggestion and posted it as an answer. I hope the format is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof:

Suppose that $C$ is relatively closed in $E$. Then there exists a closed set $A$ such that $A\cap E=C$. Now, $E\backslash C=E\cap C^c = E\cap (A \cap E)^c=E\cap (A^c \cup B^c) = (E\cap A^c)\cup (E\cap E^c)=E\cap A^c$. Since $A^c$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $E\backslash C$ is relatively open in $E$ by definition.